# How do we target-encode categorical features in multi class classification problems?

Tags: catboost, target-encoding

Say I have a multiclass problem with a dataset as this:

```py
user_id  price   target
-------+--------+-----
1         30      apple
1         20      samsung
2         32      samsung
2         40      huawei
.
.
```

where I have a lot of users i.e One Hot Encoding (OHE) is not doable. Target-encoders such as `CatBoost` have achieved great results for target encoding categorical features. The issue is, I can only find CatBoost/target-encoder for binary classification/regression (which makes sense, in some way).

Right now I have overcommed the issue by target-encode each class in the *target*, by OHE the `target` (since it often has fewer categories), and then "target-encoded" the `user_id` for each OHE encoding e.g with these two steps:

1. OHE the target

```py
user_id  price   ohe_apple   ohe_samsung   ohe_huawei
-------+-------+-----------+-------------+------------
1         30       1             0             0
1         20       0             1             0
2         32       0             1             0
2         40       0             0             1
```

2. target-encode `user_id` for each `ohe_`-column  (the numbers are just made up for the illustration):

```py
price  user_id_apple user_id_samsung  user_id_huawei
-----+--------------+----------------+---------------
30         0.5            0.6             0
20         0.5            0.6             0
32         0               1              0
40         0               0              1
.
.
```

I have achieved a notable increase of performance in e.g neural network with this approach (where OHE cannot fit into the GPU) but I wonder if there is some target-encoder for high-cardinality features (like user-id) in a multiclass classification, for e.g `CatBoost`?

Comment: Does not Catboost do a one vs all approaching multiclassification?

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/2105.13783

Comment: @CarlosMougan just by looking at the title it is for regression - I'm trying to tackle a classifcation problem

Comment: How does catboost multiclassification handle the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Feature hashing, such as `category_encoders` `HashingEncoder()` is widely applicable in such cases, with a controllable feature size/information loss tradeoff.

`category_encoders` also supplies a `PolynomialWrapper()`, automating the extension of binary target encoders to multiclass (still using OHE on the target inside).

Edit: valid point, hashing is target agnostic, so to speak.
It is a better option than OHE still, and category_encoders devs even [recommend it](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/category_encoders/issues/192) in a case of a huge amount of classes.

Comment: The OP is asking about Target Encoder not HashingEncoder